# creation of a class in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have been following the example of making a class in Pharo from the following link:
https://ci.inria.fr/pharo-contribution/job/UpdatedPharoByExample/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/book-result/PharoObjectModel/PharoObjectModel.html#fig:colorInstanceClassSide

It is the example of making a Dog and a Hyena class. First I created a package called TestC and in the Instance class I have made the following:

[image]

[image]

For what I know, and correct me if I am wrong, the instance side is where I create the methods that will work when I instantiate an object while the class side it does not need an object to be created to function; just like a static method class in Java.

The **first question** that I have at this point is why after Accepting the Changes it stills appear the ! symbol in the left part of my classes?

According to the tutorial then I should put the following code:

```
Dog class
    instanceVariableNames: 'count'
```

Now I did not where to put it, on the instance side or in the class side, I decided to put it on the instance side the following:

[image]

and the last methods that I have are the following, I put them on the class side:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tested the classes in the Transcript with the following code:

```
aDog := Dog new.
Dog count.
bDog := Dog new.
Dog count.
```

and it works, but I would like to know if I made the right decision to put those methods in the class side (**second question**), and if its right could anybody give me an example of a method to put in the instance side in this example?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First Question**

The exclamation mark `!` in front of the class is an invitation to click on it. In this case it will remind you that classes are supposed to have comments (for the sake of documentation).

**Digression**

Every class defines both the shape (or structure) and the behavior of its instances. The shape is given by the instance variables in the class creation message, such as

```
Object subclass: #Dog
  instanceVariableNames: 'name breed birthdate'
  classVariableNames: ''
  package: 'TestC'
```

For the behavior you create methods in the instance side of the class

```
breed: aString
  breed := aString
```

With this you have a full functional object

```
dog := Dog new.
dog name: 'Taylor'; breed: 'Great Dane'
```

However, classes are objects too. So, they may have their own shape. To add an instance variable to a class's shape you send the message:

```
Dog class instaceVariableNames: 'count'
```

Note that the receiver of this message is the class of the `Dog` class (a `Metaclass`), which makes sense because it is classes who shape their instances.

In your example, every time you create a new (instance of) `Dog` the `count` ivar of the `Dog` class will increase by 1. This could serve the propose of keeping track of how many instances of `Dog` have been created so far. These instances, however, will remain unaware of this fact.

**Second Question**

Yes, the ivar `count` and the methods to `initialize`, `increment` and `retrieve` it belong in the class side. Why? Because they are intended to keep track of the number of instances your class has created. Whether this is useful or not, is a different question; the fact is that they would have made no sense in the instance side (after all, lucky dogs live exciting lives without ever counting anything.)